# Show one div while hiding others when i click on a link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to untoggle (hide) all other  divs when i click on a navbar link.
So far it toggles the divs , but they stay active when i click on a new link.
I want them to .slideUp() and the one i click to slideDown
This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".output .about , .resume").hide();
    $("#about").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault;
        $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active ');
        $(".about").slideToggle("slow");

    });

    $("#resume").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault;
        $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active');
        $(".output .resume").slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

```
    <div class="cont2">
        <ul>
            <a href="#" id="about"><li class="fade-in one " >About</li></a>
            <a href="#" id="resume"><li class="fade-in two">Resume</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="fade-in three">Portfolio</li></a>
            <a href="#"><li class="fade-in four">Contact</li></a>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="output">
        <div class="about">
            <p>About</p>
        </div>

        <div class="resume">
            <p>Resume</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

EDIT : the code that works properly

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".cont1").hide();
    $(".cont1").fadeIn(1000);
    $(".output .about , .resume").hide();
    $("#about").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(".cont2 li .active").removeClass('active');

        $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active');
        $(".about").slideToggle("slow");
        $(".resume").slideUp("slow");

    });

    $("#resume").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault;
        $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active');
        $(".output .resume").slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

Comment: Just something to think about here - you're wrapping the LI tags in the A tags - <a><li></li></a> - which is not correct and won't validate. Normally, one would wrap the A tags in the LI tags - <li><a></a></li>.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that corrects that issue, along with an annotated demo of what I think you're trying to do, though it looks like balzafin might have beat me to it. http://jsfiddle.net/Yardboy/36fa4v9a/2/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would better if you just used one click event for all of your links. That way you don't have to copy your code around so much. Just use the `id` of your anchor and kind of pair it with the `divs` class (same name). You already have this is in your HTML so you don't have to change it.

Another thing is that if you want the `slideUp` (hide) effect to be noticeable, you should run the `slideDown` (show) effect in its callback. In other words, you want to wait for one animation to stop before running another.

Here's something I came up with:

```
$(".output .about , .resume").hide();

$("a").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var hiddenDiv = $(".output ." + $(this).attr("id"));
    var visibleDiv = $(".output > div:visible");

    // if all the divs are hidden, just show the desired one
    if (visibleDiv.is(":visible")) {
        visibleDiv.slideUp("slow", function () {
            hiddenDiv.slideDown("slow");
        });
    } else {
        hiddenDiv.slideDown("slow");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4cvnrh51/

Answer (score 1):

Search for the elements that have the active class and remove it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".output .about , .resume").hide();
  $("#about").click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(".about").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".resume, .portfolio, .contact").slideUp("slow");

  });

  $("#resume").click(function(e)
  {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).find('li').toggleClass('active');
    $(this).siblings().find(".active").removeClass('active');
    $(".resume").slideToggle("slow");
    $(".about, .portfolio, .contact").slideUp("slow");
  });
});
```

Comment: This just removes the css in the links , but doesnt toggle the div

Comment: Whoops. I edited the answer to slide up the other divs. I assume you'll give the Portfolio and Contact related names, so I filled in the selector under that assumption.

Comment: Adding to Joe's answer, you'll need to define an "active" class for your divs like you did for your li's - make the divs hidden unless they have the "active" class - in the js you'll toggle the "active" class on/off your divs just like you do on the li's. That will cause the divs to hide/show the way you want them to.

Comment: @JoeRCasey joe this works , but now it doesn't toggle the li active class, for example: when i toggle it, li get highlighted than when i toggle it of it slides up but the li class doesn't get removed.

Comment: Sorry. Answer edited. Attempt #3 :P http://jsbin.com/lowafuyoqu/1/edit?html,css,js,output